# how to set column text color in GridMvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewmodel

here is my code below it's in the View Layer I am struggling to change change the color of my column headings to orange. please help.

```
@model IEnumerable<uYilo_FMS.Models.vehicle_obj>

@using GridMvc.Html
@{


}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width"/>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")"></script>
<rowDefinition Height="57" width="873">

<title>@ViewBag.Title = "Title"</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Vehicles List</h3>
<div class="page-wrap">
    @Html.Grid(Model, GridRenderOptions.Create("VehiclesGrid")).Columns(columns =>

{
   columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(c => @<img class="thumbnail" src="~/Content/images/@c.ImagePath" height="80" width="80" alt="@c.ImagePath" />);
   columns.Add(c => c.displayName).Titled("Vehicle Name");
   columns.Add(c => c.make).Titled("Make");
   columns.Add(c => c.type).Titled("Type");
   columns.Add(c => c.odometer).Titled("Odometer");




}).WithPaging(5).Sortable(true).

</div>

<script>
    function getRow(vehicle_reg) {
        $.jax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DisplayTripHistory", "Home")',
            data: JSON.stringify(vehicle_reg),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function () {
                alert('SUCCESS');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After render grid you will see header of grid use

```
.grid-header
```

class,
so you can create CSS to make it change

Example:

```
.grid-header a{
color:red; }
```

You will see text header color will be Red

To know more checkout this link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/597253/Using-the-Grid-MVC-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Hope it helps!

Comment: Done.. I'm new here i didn't know i have to mask correct solutions :) thanks